# How to create a python code to count number of comment lines and lines containing whitespace in a file?

Tags: python, count, comments, whitespace, lines

How to create a python code to count number of comment lines and lines containing whitespace in a file? I have an assignment and I need to write an additional command line utility that  counts the  lines of code in my program. The utility needs to open all  .py files in the current directory(except for the code in the utility file itself), count the  lines in the file that are not blank and not comments, and output the count to the terminal.

Comment: Please list what you've done so far, and add any code you've tried. If you can, consider breaking your task into smaller sections, so that you can address each point in turn. This should make it easier to work out what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some hints that should be enough for you to solve the assignment. Check this code:

```
>>> file = open('myfile.txt')
>>> lines = file.readlines()
>>> for each_line in lines:
        print each_line
```

Replace 'myfile.txt' with an existing file and see what happens. Regarding getting files in a directory, the os module will help you here. Try the code below:

```
>>> from os import listdir
>>> mypath = '.'
>>> from os.path import isfile, join
>>> onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
>>> onlyfiles
```

With these two pieces, you should be able to solve your excercise, Python is a language very easy to learn.

Comment: thank you for the help! I got what I needed with this: